# SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER even ssl version attached to python is correct

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, tls1.2, tls1.3

When I make a request using Python's `requests` module to google `google.com`,

```
import requests
    
requests.get("https://google.com")
```

it gives me an error of

```
   raise SSLError(e, request=request)

requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with u

rl: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

I checked that the google supports `TLS 1.2/3` and also when running the command suggested in similar posts on stack overflow:

```
Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import ssl

>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION

'OpenSSL 1.1.1n  15 Mar 2022'

>>>
```

I saw from the official OpenSSL change log that the Openssl version of `1.1.1` (what I have) linked to my python supports `TLS 1.3`.

Why do I still get the error saying the version is wrong? I also tried using `Verify = False`   and it still doesn't help, also other related posts are not helping me. Any inputs are appreciated.

Comment: What do you get from `getattr(ssl, "HAS_SNI", False)`? (in some circumstances requests will use `urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl` instead of the `ssl` module itself).

Comment: ...btw -- how was all this software installed? If this happens with a stock distro version of Python we can get from Docker to reproduce the problem ourselves, that would make this a lot easier to run down.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy For that command, I am getting ```true```.  Does that mean I have to switch to the ```ssl ``` module? How can I do it? Also, this software is installed into by IT (company PC) and I don't think I can play with docker in this PC

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you have a wrong setting for proxy, because this is exactly the error you get in this case - see duplicate question. If this is not the case let me know and provide the actual proxy settings and the full stacktrace, so that I can reopen the question. *"I also tried using Verify = False  and it still doesn't help"* - it cannot help since the error is not about certificate validation.

Comment: Getting true is what we want from the above test -- it means the `ssl` module doesn't need to be patched. I suspect Steffen is correct about a proxy being in play.